# What's the purpose of the milk teeth?

Tags: parts-of-the-body, teeth

Human teeth are different from other parts of the body because they are given twice (the third we need to pay).

Does Judaism address the purpose of the creation of [the milk teeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deciduous_teeth) at infancy and their replacement later with permanent ones? What does it represent spiritually?

Comment: To the closers: What is wrong with this question? He is asking if Judaism addresses this phenomenon and gives a spiritual reason/lesson to be learned from it. Seems legitimate to me.

Comment: Both sets of teeth are present at birth (and at a point in fetal development).  What you call "milk teeth" we in the US call "baby teeth."  Occasionally a child is born with one or more teeth visible but generally they start coming in at the age of 4-9 months.  Around the age of 5-6 years, the baby teeth start falling out (the last ones come out about age 12) and the permanent teeth come in.  Only the wisdom teeth don't have a baby version.  Both sets of teeth are in the skull.  See: 
http://www.viralnova.com/child-skull/

Comment: I don't find it but I remember that the chovot halevavot addressed this. He says that it is to learn to deal with pain

Comment: Urgh, not really content with the previous answers. Cyn just states neutral and objective facts which don't answer the question and koutys answer seems so unsatisfying and left out. 'It's so we deal with pain' - what Jewish scholar would give an answer like that? Doesn't seem quite right to me. Especially since the falling out of the milk teeth is usually a painless process (albeitly a bloody one)

Comment: @Jay Here was the original question: "What's the purpose of the creation of [the milk teeth][1] in men at infancy and their replacement later with permanent ones?" - it didn't seem to have any relation to Judaism whatsoever, so I voted to close.  Now, I wouldn't.

Comment: @Anonymous these are comments, not answers.  The question asked about how (if) Judaism addresses this issue.  I couldn't answer this but I wanted to comment on what appeared to me to be an incorrect premise about the teeth.  That's why I chose to do a comment vs an answer.  I can't speak for kouty but that comment is a comment because it's not sufficient for an answer.  This is why SE has both comments and answers.

Comment: Also, teething is a horribly painful process.  Some babies do better than others but every last one of them is uncomfortable at least some of the time.  It's miserable for parents too.  Losing baby teeth isn't painless either.  It is very distracting for the kids (some teeth stay loose for months! a couple weeks is more common though) and can be physically uncomfortable too.  The actual coming out is only the end of the process and the pain is usually minimal.  Teething of the permanent teeth isn't nearly as bad as for baby teeth, but it can still be uncomfortable at times.

Comment: @kouty I can only think of [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart%2C_Second_Treatise_on_Examination.5.16?with=all&lang=bi) piece but it’s not as you recall.

Comment: @Oliver yes, I remember something else, perhaps a false reminiscing

Comment: Umm... hair falls out and grows back all the time... am I missing something?

Comment: @Loani what does this change mean "spiritually" or Kabbalically.

Comment: I get the question, but why specifically teeth and not hair, which grows back many more times than teeth